# Hacer log django

Tags: python, django

Necesito realizar un log para mi modulo de django que guarde en un templates los datos modificados en mi modelo de registros ,la verdad que estoy un poco perdido en esto,estoy desde 0 y los cursos y temas que he encontrado no los entiendo muy bien, gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow, da un [tour] y revisa [ask] para que puedas formular una pregunta que sea aceptada por la comunidad. Muestra lo que has intentado.

Comment: En la documentación de django hay mas información sobre el tema, no es necesario crear un login desde cero pues puedes reutilizar el código ya hecho por django. echale un vistoso a la doc